# Datebox not working

Tags: google-apps-script

Surprisingly all my scripts using datebox and validated for a while are not working today.
Is there a (temporary I hope) issue with this gadget? 
Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

I think you set only the ID of the DataBoxes, using the `setId` function and do not set the name, using the `setName` function. If yes, then add to all DataBoxes additional `setName` function call, i.e. if your code is

```
dateBox01.setId('dateBox01');
```

then it should be

```
dateBox01.setId('dateBox01').setName('dateBox01');
```

I had similar problem today.

Comment: Thats right. See the release notes for Aug 3 which 'fixed' an issue. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/release_notes